# Unity: Изменить размеры во время stretch

Tags: unity3d, transform

Как видите на картинке у меня панель находится в режиме stretch.

[image]

Я хочу изменить размер во время stretch (как на картинке). Слева 0, сверху 800, справа 0, снизу 120.

[image]

---

*Собственно как мне это сделать с помощью кода?*

Comment: Переключите инспектор в Debug-режим и посмотрите какие именно поля Вам необходимо в коде менять, что бы добиться нужных отступов.

Comment: @Alt_F4, да нет, он прав. Можете сами проверить. Учтите, что localPosition в данном случае это не первичные данные а вычисляемые, и менять надо sizeDelta, anchoredPosition и anchors

Comment: @trollingchar сейчас не удобно, скоро попробую

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский ваш вариант работает но что мне делать если экран будет другой?

Comment: @trollingchar Вопрос сверху хотел задать и вам тоже но упомянуть 2 участников сразу нельзя

Comment: @Alt_F4 будет работать на любом экране. Вы можете: 1) в вкладке Game задать масштабирование Free Aspect и менять размер окна с игрой 2) задать вместо Free Aspect любое разрешение экрана, и юнити подстроит окно с игрой под него

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский всё работает. Можете делать это ответом.

Comment: чуть позже оформлю ответом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы посмотреть значения полей `RectTransform` (да и других компонентов), которые могут не отображаться в обычном режиме Инспектора, переключите последний в "Debug"-режим.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что касается `RectTransform`, то значения, настроенные в режиме "Normal", могут не совпадать со значениями в "Debug" режиме и могут меняться в зависимости от положения `Pivot`